# Silently install Apache with php and files

Tags: php, c++, apache, silent-installer

I am writing a C++ installer and want to have it perform the following tasks without user interaction:

- Silently install an instance of Apache
- Silently add PHP to said apache instance
- Determine the DocumentRoot of the apache instance and copy a bunch of php files to that location

Currently I have it installing apache using this command: `apache_2.2.6-win32-x86-no_ssl.msi /passive ALLUSERS=1 SERVERADMIN=admin@localhost SERVERNAME=localhost SERVERDOMAIN=localhost SERVERPORT=80`. This silently installs apache with the specified settings and leaves the services automatically started. Perfect.

The problem is that after this I don't know how to get the DocumentRoot that Apache uses (it is by default `C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache\htdocs` on my test computer), so I don't know where to send the files. So I either need to:

- Control the location of htdocs (preferable)
- Find a way to dynamically grab the DocumentRoot

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to parse the `Apache/conf/httpd.conf` file then change the `DocumentRoot` value to what location you want him to point at.

Find this

```
DocumentRoot ".*"
```

Change it to

```
DocumentRoot "Your Location"
```

To find the location of the httpd.conf knowing that the default installation folder of apache is Programe Files ...

Using the win 32 API

```
TCHAR pf[MAX_PATH];
SHGetSpecialFolderPath(
    0,
    pf, 
    CSIDL_PROGRAM_FILES, 
    FALSE );
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762204(VS.85).aspx

Then add `\Apache Software Foundation\Apache\conf\httpd.conf` to the program files folder to locate the httpd.conf file

Comment: Okay that makes sense, thanks. The problem is, how do I find the path to `Apache/conf/httpd.conf`? Sorry I'm missing something obvious :S

Comment: @user1014679 I edited my answer locate the program files folder then you'll find the apache installation folder and the httpd.conf.

Comment: Okay fantastic.. would this work on both 64 and 32 bit systems (i.e. "Program Files" / "Program Files (x86)")?

Comment: @user1014679 That's exactly the point of retreive the Program Files directory using the win32 api, it will work for any systems ;)

Comment: That's brilliant. Thanks for your help, I'll give that a go and let you know how I get on!